# How can I use Wordpress REST API with NodeJs

Tags: json, node.js, wordpress, rest, express

I want some good example for using Wordpress REST API with Node.js using Express EJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-rest-api

Note:

> This is a client for the WordPress REST API. It is under active development, and should be considered beta software.

```
npm install --save wordpress-rest-api
```

example:

```
var WP = require( 'wordpress-rest-api' );
var wp = new WP({ endpoint: 'http://src.wordpress-develop.dev' });
// Callbacks 
wp.posts().get(function( err, data ) {
    if ( err ) {
        // handle err 
    }
    // do something with the returned posts 
});

// Promises 
wp.posts().then(function( data ) {
    // do something with the returned posts 
}).catch(function( err ) {
    // handle error 
});
```

Comment: "This module has been deprecated"